# show duplicate data with awk print $2,$3,$4 in a single line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting, awk

If I have a 2 lists that contain the following (examples):

```
list1
x;00:26:82:50:00:00;192.168.1.195;COMPUTER1
x;00:26:82:50:11:11;192.168.1.195;COMPUTER2
x;00:26:82:50:22:22;192.168.1.196;COMPUTER3

list2
x;00:26:82:50:11:11;192.168.1.197;COMPUTER3
```

When i run this commands show me duplicates:

```
awk -F\; '{print $2}' list* | sort | uniq -d
out: 00:26:82:50:11:11
awk -F\; '{print $3}' list* | sort | uniq -d
out: 192.168.1.195
awk -F\; '{print $4}' list* | sort | uniq -d
out: COMPUTER3
```

**My question is:**

How can I launch the command (awk -F\;..etc) on a single line and get the same results?

PD: without &&

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple script right from the command line, using cut(1) instead of awk(1), like this:

```
$ for field in 2 3 4; do cut -d\; -f${field} list* | sort | uniq -d; done
```

Comment: I have another cuestion about this. In https://superuser.com/questions/1199802/bash-and-funcion-to-detect-duplicate-data