# bash and function to detect duplicate data

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, awk

In [this example](https://superuser.com/questions/1199735/show-duplicate-data-with-awk-print-2-3-4-in-a-single-line), I mention that I have 2 lists.

```
list1
x;00:26:82:50:00:00;192.168.1.195;COMPUTER1
x;00:26:82:50:11:11;192.168.1.195;COMPUTER2
x;00:26:82:50:22:22;192.168.1.196;COMPUTER3

list2
x;00:26:82:50:11:11;192.168.1.197;COMPUTER3
```

And when I execute the command (thanks to [ccs242](https://superuser.com/users/718614/ccs242)):

```
for field in 2 3 4; do cut -d\; -f${field} list* | sort | uniq -d; done
```

I get duplicates

```
00:26:82:50:11:11
192.168.1.195
COMPUTER3
```

Now, I want to automate this process using a bash script, so if it does not find duplicates, run a certain command, but if the script detects duplicate, aborts and leaves the duplicates in in /var/log/syslog

This is my script:

```
 pathlist=/etc/doc

 function duplicate(){
     acls=`for field in 2 3 4; do cut -d\; -f${field} $pathlist/list* | sort | uniq -d; done`
     if [ ${acls} == '' ]; then
     echo OK
     #run a command foo
 else
     echo "Duplicate Data. Abort. Check /var/log/syslog"
     echo $acls >> /var/log/syslog
     exit
  fi
 }
 duplicate
```

The problem is here:

```
  [ ${acls} == '' ]
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is more than one duplicate, then `$acls` will contain a space for each new-line and the command is then syntactically incorrect. What you need is:-

```
[ "${acls}" == "" ]
```

This forces the comparison to be between two strings. As in your question, you could use `''` instead of `""`, but I prefer to use the same type of quotes on both sides of a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
if [ -z ${acls} ]
```

Comment: Line 5: [: too many arguments

Comment: Please edit your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to explain a bit more about how this command works and what it should accomplish.